# How to rank dataframe depending on a group of rows in a column?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe :

```
+-----+----------+---------+
|num  |Timestamp |frequency|
+-----+----------+---------+
|20.0 |1632899456|4        |
|20.0 |1632901256|4        |
|20.0 |1632901796|4        |
|20.0 |1632899155|4        |
|10.0 |1632901743|2        |
|10.0 |1632899933|2        |
|91.0 |1632899756|1        |
|32.0 |1632900776|1        |
|41.0 |1632900176|1        |
+-----+----------+---------+
```

I want to add a column containing the rank of each frequency. The new dataframe would be like this :

```
+-----+----------+---------+------------+
|num  |Timestamp |frequency|rank        |
+-----+----------+---------+------------+
|20.0 |1632899456|4        |1           |
|20.0 |1632901256|4        |1           | 
|20.0 |1632901796|4        |1           |
|20.0 |1632899155|4        |1           |
|10.0 |1632901743|2        |2           |
|10.0 |1632899933|2        |2           |
|91.0 |1632899756|1        |3           |
|32.0 |1632900776|1        |3           |
|41.0 |1632900176|1        |3           |
+-----+----------+---------+------------+
```

I am using Spark version 2.4.3 and SQLContext, with scala language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df.withColumn("rank", dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy(desc("frequency")))
```